# How can i get the username and domain name of client system in java as i can get the ip address and host name using request.getRemoteHost

Tags: java, inetaddress

```
        out.print( "ip : "+request.getRemoteHost() );

        InetAddress ip=  InetAddress.getByName(""+request.getRemoteHost());

        String host=ip.getHostName();
        InetAddress host1=ip;
        out.print("host "+host);
```

How can i get the username and domain name of client system in java as i can get the ip address and host name using `request.getRemoteHost` ..

using whoami am getting the server pc username. while i need the logged in username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find like below:

```
    System.out.println(System.getenv().get("USERDOMAIN"));
    System.out.println(System.getenv().get("USERNAME"));
```

User name can be obtained as below:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
```

Comment: [with this am getting the server domain.. i need that domain and user from where the user is logined.. my server domain name is reflecting on other pc]

Comment: with this am getting the server domain.. i need that domain and user from where the user is logined.. my server domain name is reflecting on other pc

Comment: Can you check if USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE is available?